# OpenCV 2 - How to switch webcam flash?

Tags: winapi, opencv, driver, webcam

I am just curious if it is possible to control a generic laptop webcam's flash. Is that possible using OpenCV? (I don't think so). Maybe with WinAPI? Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll find an answer in here:

http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/can-webcams-be-turned-on-without-the-indicator-light

Good luck!

Comment: I've read this question and some anserws, but I didn't find any solution for my problem (I think, I have to play with camera drivers..). But thanks for the link ;)